# regex in $_POST variable

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, post

I am working on an addon for wordpress - woocommerce. I am using the plugin "Woocommerce Product Addons" - with this addon i can insert for example a drop down select list for the property "color" which contains three colors - red, yellow, black.  This addon is on each product site now but the form name has on each product a different name. That is the reason why i don't know how to fetch the data with less code.

**On one product site i have the select list with this name:**

```
<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-12822-variante-0">
```

**And on another product site i have the same addon but another name:**

```
<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-12834-variante-0">
```

You can see from this example, that the number inside the name changes on each site.

I need one code which can work on all product sites, that's why i was thinking maybe i can insert regex somehow inside the **$_POST['regex']** but how does that work?

I need this regex "**((addon)-((\d)+)-)(farbe)-(0|1|2|3)**".

That in the end i have something like

```
$variant = $_POST['regexp'];
```

which works automatically on each product site.

I hope there is any workaround and thanks in advance for every suggestion.

Comment: Does this do what your looking for? '/addon-[1-9]+-variante-[012]{1}/'. To check, loop over the post values check that a preg_match is true, then do whatever else you need

Comment: Hey, it is not the regex what is not working. I am just asking how to use at this position regex at all? Because i just found  the php function "preg_match" but i think it is not exactly what i am looking for or if it is i don't know how to use it inside   $_POST['  ']

Comment: Ah I see sorry. Ok something like a foreach:  <?php   foreach($_POST as $sPostVal){if(preg_match($pattern, $sPostVal)){//do something } }  ?>

Comment: You can use `preg_grep()` on the `array_keys()` of `$_POST` to find all field names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `preg_grep` to extract the elements you need from the $_POST array:

<s>`$addonFields = array_flip(preg_grep('(your_pattern)', array_flip($_POST)));`</s>

**Edit:** As @CaTeR noted the code above won't work if there are multiple occurrences of the same values (or for example multiple empty values). See the other answers below, or use something like this to get the fields you want:

```
$addonFields = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip(preg_grep('/pattern/', array_keys($_POST))));
```

Comment: Thank you, i think this is what i am looking for. I will try it and inform you.

Comment: Be Warned: _If a value has several occurrences, the latest key will be used as its value, and all others will be lost._ [PHP.net - array_flip()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php) to get the `keys` of the `array` and after that using [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-grep.php) you could get the correct `keys`. With the next line, you will get an indexed array with all the `addons` fields contained in `$_POST` `array`.

> **Note:** With [array_values](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php) you will get a new `array` with new ordered `keys`, so you could get the value that you want getting the proper index.

```
array_values(preg_grep('/^addon\-\d+\-variante-\d+$/', array_keys($_POST)));
```

Here you have an [Ideone](http://ideone.com/YN88Bl) example to understand the functionality of the previous code.

Now, the next function gets the value of the first `addon` variable from `$_POST` variable for you (Supposing that you want to get a single `addon` variable in each page):

```
function getAddonValue($post){

    $reg = '/^addon\-\d+\-variante-\d+$/';

    return $post[array_values(preg_grep($reg, array_keys($post)))[0]];

}
```

Here you have an [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Q4ohtn) snippet with the full example.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what data will be received by post and wish to run a regex on the data you could do something like this:

```
<?php foreach($_POST as $sPostKey => $sPostVal){
    if(preg_match($pattern, $sPostVal)){
    //do something with match
    }
 } ?>
```

Assuming $pattern is the regex. The $sPostKey is the key and $sPostVal  contains the data